# Intel Edison with Kinect

Tags: kinect, intel, intel-edison

Can I connect the Kinect to Intel Edison with libfreenect?

I have been looking for information but find nothing. I know that It is possible to connect to Raspbery Pi but anything about Intel Edison.I'm especially interested in depth. I have not found other compatible cameras

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use Kinect from arduino. You may read [this](http://www.intorobotics.com/7-tutorials-start-working-kinect-arduino/). Intel Edison is a kind of Arduino board, so, you can connect the Kinect to Intel Edison. I don't know if it requires libfreenect.

Comment: It really is not possible. Kinect connects to PC and PC to Arduino but not from the Kinect to Arduino.

Comment: you can use Edison's WiFi to connect to PC and then PC to Kinect. Yet, A PC is needed though ... just an idea.

Comment: I found a style pc to Raspberry Pi and I think will serve me , thanks for the answers!